# Obtener registros de tabla en respuesta a clic de otra tabla y mostrarlos

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo dos tablas en una vista, una de ellas esta oculta y aparece cuando doy clic en una row de la primera tabla

**Tabla oculta:**

```
 @model  Tuple<IEnumerable<web.Areas.Periodo.Models.PeriodoViewModel>,
           IEnumerable<web.Areas.Periodo.Models.PeriodoPagoViewModel>>
<div id="SegundaTabla" style="display:none">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="portlet box">
        <div class="portlet-title">
          <div class="caption">
          <div class="tools">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse" data-original-title="" title=""> </a>
          </div>
        </div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dt-responsive" width="100%" id="tbl-listado">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th data-priority="1"> Periodo Pago </th>
                  <th data-priority="2"> Estatus </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
        <tbody>
      <tr>


        @if (Model.Item2 != null) { foreach (var item in Model.Item2) {
             <tr class="select" id="@item.IdPeriodoPago">
                 <td>@item.sTipoPeriodo</td>
                 <td>@item.Estatus</td>
             </tr>
          } }  
</tbody>



    </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para hacer aparecer la tabla lo hago cambiando la clase con un simple jQuery (cambiando la propiedad `display` de css):

```
   $('.select').each(function (index) {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    var row = $(this);
                    var id = row.attr('id').split('-')[1];

                    row.css({ 'background-color': 'aqua' });
                    $('#SegundaTabla').css({ 'display': 'block' });


                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Periodo/Periodo/IndexSelect',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { id: id }
                    }); 
                });
            });

Controlador:

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexSelect(int? id)
    {

        List<PeriodoPagoViewModel> LPGVM = new List<PeriodoPagoViewModel>();
        var lista2 = PPS.Listar(x=>x.IdPeriodoMensual == id && x.EstatusRegistro, includeProperties: "TipoPeriodo");
        foreach (var l in lista2)
        {
            PeriodoPagoViewModel PVM = new PeriodoPagoViewModel();
            PVM.sTipoPeriodo = l.TipoPeriodo.Nombre;
            if (l.Estatus == "A")
                PVM.Estatus = "Abierto";
            else if (l.Estatus == "X")
                PVM.Estatus = "Calculado";
            else if (l.Estatus == "C")
                PVM.Estatus = "Cerrado";
            else if (l.Estatus == "P")
                PVM.Estatus = "Pendiente";
            else
                PVM.Estatus = "";
            LPGVM.Add(PVM);
        }
        return View("Index", LPGVM);
    }
```

El controlador regresa el objeto `LPGVM` con una lista de objetos. Por lo cual el flujo es el siguiente:

Se da clic en la primera tabla, esta tabla envia el id al controlador y el controlador regresa la lista de objetos. Mi pregunta es: 
Que es lo que tengo que hacer para que mi tabla se llene una vez de clic en la primera tabla y el controlador regrese la lista de objetos?

Como obtengo los objetos en la vista y después los muestro en el body de mi tabla? Gracias!

Intenté agregar en mi llamada ajax la propiedad success:

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Periodo/Periodo/IndexSelect',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { id: id },
                    success: function (response) 
                    { alert(response.status); }
```

pero me regresa:

> success is not defined

después intenté lo siguiente:

```
                    $.ajax({
                    url: '/Periodo/Periodo/IndexSelect',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { id: id },
                    success: handleResponse 


function handleResponse(data) { alert(data); }
```

Pero tampoco funciona. Alguien que me pueda ayudar? Saludos

Comment: A ver si entiendo mejor. Lo que deseas es que en el Index salga una tabla y al dar click en una Fila, la cual corresponde a un Item se muestre una segunda tabla con los objetos de ese Item?

Comment: Exacto. Es lo que quiero @VicenteAlmea

Answer (score 0):

Voy a utilizar dos modelos diferentes en este ejemplo, Area y Trabajador, con relación 1-n, donde un area puede tener varios trabajadores.

en la vista Index de Area:

```
 @model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Area>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr id="@item.Id" class="table-row" style="cursor: pointer">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<div id="tabla2"></div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ($) {
            $(".table-row").on("click", function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");                  
                $("#tabla2").load("@Url.Action("Trabajadores", "Areas")/"+ id);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Si te fijas en la tabla de la vista index para Area, cada `<tr>` tendrá como `id` el `id` del item que va a mostrar, y class="table-row" eso lo he difinido así para poder recogerlo más abajo en mi java script, también le apliqué estilo `cursor:pointer` para que al pasar el cursor se muestre cada `<tr>` como un link. El objetivo es recoger el Id del item seleccionado y conformar una Url que va a ser renderizada en el `<div id="tabla2">`. Lo que vas a renderizar en tabla2 es una vista parcial con el resultado de la acci'on que hemos llamado con java script. ejemplo:

```
public class AreasController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: /Areas/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Areas.ToList());
        }

        //Esta es la acción que llamamos al dar click en un tr de la tabla
        public ActionResult Trabajadores(int id)
        {
            var trabajadores = db.Trabajadores.Where(t => t.AreaId == id).ToList();

            return PartialView("_ListadoTrabajadoresPartial", trabajadores);
        }
....
}
```

y en Views/Areas creo la vista parcial con el contenido que se va a renderizar en tabla2:

_ListadoTrabajadoresPartial.cshtml

```
    @model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Trabajador>


<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

De esta forma al dar click en un area se mustra una tabla con todos sus trabajadores en la misma vista Index. Espero te sea de ayuda.